# Rails routes for particular setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I am new to rails and have a question on how to best route my particular application. I am using a legacy database so the schema is already set and complicates things a bit. The layout of the app includes a top navigation bar that includes 'users' and then for a particular 'user' there is another navigation bar to display/edit a variety of forms. For example once a particular 'user' is queried there are seperate forms for 'general information' and 'account information', etc.

The setup I have now is to have a 'users' namespace to correspond to the top level navigation and in the namespace have the second level of navigation: 'general', 'project', etc. With this setup each form selected from the second level of navigation has its own controller which seems a bit odd.

```
  namespace :users do
    resources :general, :project
  end
```

This allows me to have the following urls where :id belongs to 'user'

```
/users/general/:id
/users/general/:id/edit
/users/account/:id
/users/account/:id/edit
```

Does this seem reasonable or does anyone have any other ideas on how to deal with a nested navigation setup in a RESTful way? The legacy database complicates in that I do not have a 'general','account' model or DB table. For each form I need to pull from several models/tables that have associations with the 'user' model. Having a 'general' controller while not having a 'general' model does not seem very rails like which is what is bothering me.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you considered creating a "general" model (not a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base) to manage operations on the various underlying tables when the "general" attributes are CRUDed? The underlying tables can all inherit from ActiveRecord::Base to manage persistence, and the general model would manipulate them to maintain the records in the db. Your general controller then treats an instance of the general class more or less like an AR model, but when you CRUD it, the model logic kicks in and manages what's really happening in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You're headed in the right direction, however, namespaces aren't going to help you maintain the assocations you're looking for.  Instead, I'd try this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :general, :project
end
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem I have though is that I do not have general and project models in part due to the legacy database. The 'general' form may contain address information stored in one model/table and phone information in another.